# "Expected unqualified-id" for ofstream 

Tags: c++, ofstream

I wrote the following C++ program, but at the line where I used `out_stream.open()`, it keeps telling me that there are errors about "unknown typename 'out_stream'" and "Expected unqualified-id".

I am new to C++ and I think I just copied down the lines from my textbook, so I can't figure out where it's wrong. Please bear with me if it is a really simple mistake.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions.hpp>


std::ofstream out_stream;
out_stream.open("output.txt");


int main()
{
    std::cout<<"hello world!";
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot to this

```
out_stream.open("output.txt");
```

outside of a function. Put it inside the main().

```
int main()
{
    out_stream.open("output.txt");
    std::cout<<"hello world!";
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks you!! But just curious, is there a moral behind this restriction? Why isn't it allowed to use its member function outside another function?

Comment: There is no "moral" involved, the language rules just say that code is supposed to be inside a function. You actually *can* open the file directly in the declaration by using one of its constuctors that calls open for you `std::ofstream out_stream("output.txt");`.

Comment: Thanks for the constructor method @BoPersson